# Mostrar Mapas de google en una aplicacion Java

Tags: java-swing, google-maps, webview

Hasta hace unos días mi aplicación ha estado mostrando los mapas de Google, pero algo ha cambiado en Google que ya no me los muestra. He estado buscando información y todos los ejemplos que he encontrado ocurre lo mismo.
Estoy usando java8.

Espero podáis ayudarme o darme alguna solucion.

Este es mi código

maps.html (cuando lo ejecuto este archivo html funciona correctamente en un navegador, por lo que descarto que este fallando desde este lugar)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Maps</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&callback=initMap"></script>
  <script>
        var geocoder;
        var map;
        var markers = [];
        function initialize() {
          geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.420088,-3.688810);
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng
          }
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        }
        var prev_infowindow =false; //lo utilizamos para obtener la ultima ventana abierta y poder cerrar al abrir la seguiente
        function searchAddress(direccion,nombreCliente,idCliente,idProveedor)
        {
          var address = direccion;
          geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) 
          {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
            {
                var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">"'+nombreCliente+'"</h1>'+
                    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                    '<p>'+direccion+'</p>';
                    if(idCliente>0)
                    {
                        contentString += '<p><a href="#" onclick="callJavaFXGoToCliente('+idCliente+')">Ver Ficha del Cliente</a></p>';
                    }
                    else if(idProveedor>0)
                    {
                        contentString += '<p><a href="#" onclick="callJavaFXGoToProveedor('+idProveedor+')">Ver Ficha del Proveedor</a></p>';
                    }
                    contentString +='</div>'+
                    '</div>';

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString
                });
                
              map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  position: results[0].geometry.location,
                  title: nombreCliente
              });
              markers.push(marker);
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() 
              {
                if( prev_infowindow ) 
                {
                    prev_infowindow.close();//si hay una venta abierta la cerramos
                }

                prev_infowindow = infowindow;//almacenamos la ventana que esta abierta
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
                
              });
            } 
            else 
            {
              alert('No se ha encontrado la dirección, ERROR: ' + status);
            }
          });
        }
        
        // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
        function setAllMap(map) 
        {
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
          {
            markers[i].setMap(map);
          }
        }

        // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
        function clearMarkers() 
        {
          setAllMap(null);
        }

        // Shows any markers currently in the array.
        function showMarkers() 
        {
          setAllMap(map);
        }

        // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
        function deleteMarkers() 
        {
          clearMarkers();
          markers = [];
        }
        
        function weatherLayer()
        {
            var weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
                temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.CELSIUS
            });
            weatherLayer.setMap(map);

            var cloudLayer = new google.maps.weather.CloudLayer();
            cloudLayer.setMap(map);
        }
        
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        
        function callJavaFXGoToCliente(idCliente){            
            app.goToClienteCallFromJavascript(idCliente);
        }
        
        function callJavaFXGoToProveedor(idProveedor){            
            app.goToProveedorCallFromJavascript(idProveedor);
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <input id="address" type="text" value="">
      <input type="button" value="Buscar" onclick="searchAddress(document.getElementById('address').value, document.getElementById('address').value, -1, -1)">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

y este e mi codigo java

```
public GoogleMapViewerJDialog(boolean showJPanelClientes)
{
    initComponents();

    jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    jPanelMap.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    jPanelMap.add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    jPanelClientes.setVisible(showJPanelClientes);

    ResourceMap resourceMap = Application.getInstance(App.class).getContext().getResourceMap();
    this.setIconImage(resourceMap.getImageIcon("icon.xeasy32x32").getImage());
    jXList1.setHighlighters(HighlighterFactory.createSimpleStriping(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255)));

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            initMaps();
        }
    });

}

@Action
public void initMaps()
{
    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {

                webview = new WebView();

                //Creamos la conexion entre el javascript y el codigo java
                webview.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
                        new ChangeListener<State>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState)
                    {
                        if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED)
                        {
                            JSObject window = (JSObject) webview.getEngine().executeScript("window");
                            window.setMember("app", new JavaFxConnector());
                            actualizarMapa();
                        }
                    }
                });
                JSObject window = (JSObject) webview.getEngine().executeScript("window");
                window.setMember("app", new JavaFxConnector());
                //webview.getEngine().loadContent(gCH.getHtmlMapDireccionesClientes(clientes));
                //Leemos del package com.googlemaps los maps                    
                webview.getEngine().loadContent(readFile(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/googlemaps/maps.html")));
                //Cargamos el webview en el panel                 
                jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(webview));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(MapaJPanelFX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

El error que me indica java es que no se ha definido la variable geocoder al intentar añadir un marcador, por lo que entiendo que desde el webview no esta consiguiendo ejecutar esta línea en javascript ->geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Java8 usas?

Comment: Estoy usando jdk1.8.0_202

Comment: Pudiera ser por una actualización de Java, si te es posible prueba con 8u51.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero esto no ha solucionado nada. Sigo igual.